# How do I drown Whorls?

Tags: achievements, risk-of-rain

There is an achievement (and item unlock) in Risk of Rain with the requirement "Drown 20 Whorls". How do I accomplish this? I would guess it has something to do with the "Sunken Tomb" level, but the Whorls survive just fine underwater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "drown" the whorls by making them fall off the bottom of the screen on the Sunken Tomb level.